# C# DataGridView: Disable CellEnter event for Columns

Tags: c#, sorting, exception, events, datagridview

I've created columns and retrieved data from a database to populate a `DataGridView`.

I have a `CellEnter` event that fires and processes the selected row of the grid. However, the `DataGridViewColumn` also triggers `CellEnter` and when I click the column header to sort the data, the program tries to process it instead and throws an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception.

How might I disable CellEnter being called for the columns?

Comment: Why not check the e.rowindex ?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar situation in the past. The following has worked for me.

This example shows how to avoid the situation where the processing you do in `myCellEnterEvent()` causes another call to `myCellEnterEvent`. If you allow `WasICalledBy()`to run through the entire stack, and if you log the `GetMethod().Name` for each frame, you will see all of the various situations that cause your event to be fired and you can filter on those specific situations in the most appropriate way for your specific circumstances.

```
private myCellEnterEvent( object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WasICalledBy("myCellEnterEvent"))
        return;

    // do the things you really want to do here...
}

private bool WasICalledBy(string MethodName)
{
    bool MethodFound = false;
    int StartLevel = 2; // ignore this (WasICalledBy) method and ignore the method that called
                        // WasICalledBy(), so that the caller can determine if it resulted in a call to itself.

    StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
    for (int nFrame = StartLevel; nFrame < st.FrameCount; nFrame++)
    {
        if (st.GetFrame(nFrame).GetMethod().Name.ToUpper() == MethodName.ToUpper())
        {
            MethodFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }   
    return MethodFound;
}
```

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the edits. In reference to the highlighted method names in the text portion of my answer, is that "in-line code" markup?